# what is DefaultBufferMaxRows for two source?

Tags: ssis

I have 2 questions about ssis buffer.
1) In my ssis package i am using 1 data flow task contain 2 oledb source,2 oledb destination.Both are independent.All setting are keeping default,We know the DefaultBufferMaxRows is 10000 rows.So,if i run this package,whether the number of record per buffer is 10000 per each or 5000 per each?

2) I have tried to use ssis logging(xml and database),but i dont know,it is not showing any thing.It is creating xml file,but there is no usefull information(other that some xml tags).also it is not creating any table. 
logging event window also not displaying any thing.Can u please help me...

Answer (score 1):

Addressing the second question as I'd need to do research on the first.

I find logging to SQL Server to be my preferred destination. The other options (file, event viewer, trace file, etc) are fine and dandy but to sieve through that data, a query is my tool.

You state it isn't showing anything useful, what did you expect it to show and what have you selected?

I generally select the following events: OnInformation, OnError, OnWarning, OnPreExecute, OnPostExecute. The first three provide information about what's wrong, potentially wrong or could be improved with my packages. The last two I use to establish duration of various tasks.

Check them only at the top level. I had a coworker that had checked the above events at the package level but on each sub task they checked one event. They had anticipated it would inherit the logging established at the root and add in the single event selected at that level. The reverse was true: only the innermost checked items were logged.

Where does everything get logged? In 2005, it'll be found in `dbo.sysdtslog90`. For 2008 forward, it can be found in `dbo.sysssislog` The master copy of this table exists in msdb but if you point your OLEDB connection to a different catalog (SALES, Adventureworks, etc) the first invocation of the package will result in that table being copied down into the target catalog.

Comment: Hi thanks for reply,Please let me know once u get the answer for the first question.